# Error when declaring a range and then using it for a sum

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the following piece of code

```
Dim range_to_sum As Range
range_to_sum = ColumnLetter & "2" & ":" & ColumnLetter & lrow
```

where
ColumnLetter = C
lrow = 6

When I do this I get the following message which is

"Object variable or with block variable not set"
Not sure of why I am getting this message.

What I'm trying to do is use this range to them sum some values, so I have a for loop and on that for loop I've got this line of code

```
Worksheets("Data_Graph2").Range(sum_result) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(range_to_sum)
```

but this doesn't seem to work unless range_to_sum is declared as a range which is what I'm trying to do in the first piece of code that I was showing on this question.

Comment: `Set range_to_sum  =`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare it a range it needs a range not a string:

```
Dim range_to_sum As Range
Set range_to_sum = ActiveSheet.Range(ColumnLetter & "2" & ":" & ColumnLetter & lrow)
```

Or you can declare it a string:

```
Dim range_to_sum As String
range_to_sum = ColumnLetter & "2" & ":" & ColumnLetter & lrow
```

Then in the sum you would use:

```
Worksheets("Data_Graph2").Range(sum_result) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ActiveSheet(Range(range_to_sum))
```